# Term describing fishing worms

Tags: expressions

What term is used to describe a number of fishing worms? 
Examples:
A covey of quail or
a pride of lions

Comment: The broader idea here is "terms of venery."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too narrowly scoped. Worms maybe, but those used for fishing? Would you expect a collective term for only those lions that are albino, or left-handed violinists?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Albiniprides and Sinifiddlers, respectively.

Comment: @jimm 101 Were those words, they'd not be collective nouns any more than 'lions' is.

Answer (score 1):

> Worms come in groups called a bed, clew, bunch, or clat

Source: http://www.writers-free-reference.com/172groupnames.htm
Also: http://www.collectivenouns.biz/list-of-collective-nouns/collective-nouns-animals/, http://www.macwebguru.com/2011/06/24/collective-nouns/

Of course, you can also choose, if applicable,

> A Can of Worms

http://mentalfloss.com/article/31039/how-did-term-open-can-worms-originate

Comment: http://users.tinyonline.co.uk/gswithenbank/collnoun.htm Yep, a clew of worms. Not in the book: An Exultation of Larks

Comment: An interesting point re invertebrates on that link:  a stuck of jellyfish (fluther, smack or smuth). A culture of bacteria and that's about it in that category. It's funny how some of these terms soldier on and others have been extinguished, as it were.